# Entity Framework Core Or Normal Sql Command Object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have to create a solution in Asp.net core and I have to use a stored procedure based approach. So is it feasible to use Entity Framework core for the application?
Because data return from the stored procedure, not an object declared in Entity Core

Comment: Based on *what* criteria? What are you trying to do? How do you want the results to look like? SqlCommand returns objects as well, of a certain type. EF Core can return dynamic results too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to understand what is needed. 
Entity Framework & using normal SQl command, both has it's pros & cons.

Basic points are :

**Entity Framework**

1. Can act as ORM for different databases, if you application uses two or more databases like SQL server & oracle. Almost same code can be used. Also it is easier to switch from one db to another.
2. EF has both code first & db first, also maintains connections & query generation so less concern for SQL injection & faster changes
3. Using EF however if your team has many developers who are committing EF changes frequently it is hard to merge internal layers code conflicts for EF.
4. If you have strong middleware & caching, EF can be optimised for application caching.

**SQL Command object**

1. More control over SQL since query generated in EF are at runtime so hard to analyse & optimize indices, & execution plan.
2. Need to take care for sql injections, parameter sniffing issues.
3. No issues for code merges till DB design is done with consultation in large Dev Teams.
4. SQL Command objects are easier to debug & analyse in maintenance with less effort in change since you need not to update whole EF files & related code.

Teams with dedicated DBA & large server for DB choose SQL command, Teams with small agile team with full stack dev with strong middleware usually go for EF.

Both of them are good for some use cases & none of them is silver bullet for all. 
so pick what suits you best.

Comment: We mostly concerned about the performance of application related to execution. So what would be your suggestion?

Comment: Depends on your schema, number of reads, concurrent users/connections, amount of data read in requests, joins/indexes required, frequency of insert/update/deletion, lot of more factors. In general, for disconnected architecture with complex joins & concurrent users, you have more control via SQL command since you have more control over transactions, locks, read write  & can optimize query plan better

Comment: If you have more reads, less update/inserts, less complex transactions, joins & have good middleware caching EF can also out perform .

Answer (score 4):

EF Core provides the following methods to execute a stored procedure:

1. `DbSet<TEntity>.FromSql()`
2. `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`

   `var data = context.DbSet<TEntity>.FromSql("SPName").ToList();`

   `var rowsAffected = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sql command");`

For more details : [entityframeworktutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx)

and for use fields that not exist in model you can declare these in model and use `NotMapped` attribute. [NotMapped Attribute](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

And for **mapping stored procedures, fluently** look at this [link](https://www.sinclairinat0r.com/2017/05/06/entity-framework-core--mapping-stored-procedures,-fluently)

Comment: Thank you for an answer, Yes, I know  I can do that, but it will return table specific entity.

Comment: @Hrishikesh for mapping stored procedures look this solution : [link](https://www.sinclairinat0r.com/2017/05/06/entity-framework-core--mapping-stored-procedures,-fluently)